# Find the size of selected image from gallery in android

Tags: android, basic4android

I use **basic4android** and I want to know the size of selected image from gallery.

my code is :

```
      Dim PicChooser As ContentChooser
    PicChooser.Initialize("PicChooser")
    PicChooser.Show("image/*", "Select a pic")

Sub PicChooser_Result(Success As Boolean, Dir As String, FileName As String)
If Success = True Then
        Dim inp As InputStream
        inp = File.OpenInput(Dir, FileName)
        Dim btm As Bitmap
        btm.Initialize2(inp)
end if
end Sub
```

I use below method in b4a but it doesn't work.

```
File.Size(Dir,FileName)
```

it returns zero because Dir and Filename in this sub doesn't really shows the path of the file.

Comment: Then what do they show?

Comment: they show another thing that doesn't contain file name !

Comment: Yes i understood. I knew already. I asked what they show. Please tell.

Comment: Dir and file name are : ContentDir , content://media/external/images/media/2611

Comment: That is a content uri path. Not a file system path. So you cannot use the File class. Normaly 'in java' one would use `getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri)`. Google for that and then try to find the equivalent in basic.

Comment: so in java how can i find the file size from this dir and file name (URI) ? i can use java code in basic.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere i found this maybe untested code:

```
public static String getContentSizeFromUri(Context context, Uri uri) {
    String contentSize = null;
    String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.SIZE };

    CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(
            context,
            uri, proj, null, null, null);

    Cursor cursor = cursorLoader.loadInBackground();

    if(cursor != null)
        {
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.SIZE);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst() )
            contentSize = cursor.getString(column_index);
        }

    return contentSize;
}
```

Check if return value is null before use.

Answer (score 0):

If you already get the Uri of the file, you can use the following code to get some information

```
            if (uri != null) {                    
                File file = new File(uri.getPath());
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                try {
                    jsonObject.put("FileName", file.getName());
                    jsonObject.put("FilePath", file.getAbsolutePath());
                    jsonObject.put("FileSize", file.length());                              
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```